# How to translate the logical expression of solutions to list?

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following code to obtain the solutions to a system of polynomial equations

```
Func5[B_] := 
  Module[{a, b, c, sa, ca, sb, cb, sc, cc, sd, cd, vec, trigs, polys, 
    allfuns, gb, sol, oldeqns, neweqns}, vec = {a, b, c, d, 0};
   trigs = -B . Sin[Transpose[B] . vec];
   polys = 
    TrigExpand /@ trigs /. {Sin[a] -> sa, Sin[b] -> sb, Sin[c] -> sc, 
      Sin[d] -> sd, Cos[a] -> ca, Cos[b] -> cb, Cos[c] -> cc, 
      Cos[d] -> cd};
   allfuns = 
    Join[
     polys, {sa^2 + ca^2 - 1, sb^2 + cb^2 - 1, sc^2 + cc^2 - 1, 
      sd^2 + cd^2 - 1}];
   gb = GroebnerBasis[allfuns, {sa, sb, sc, sd}, {ca, cb, cc, cd}];
   sol = 
    Reduce[gb == 0] /. {sa -> Sin[a], sb -> Sin[b], sc -> Sin[c], 
      sd -> Sin[d], ca -> Cos[a], cb -> Cos[b], cc -> Cos[c], 
      cd -> Cos[d]};
   oldeqns = And @@ Thread[trigs == 0];
   neweqns = FullSimplify[oldeqns && sol];
   all1 = Union[allfuns, gb];
    Reduce[
      neweqns && 0 <= a < 2 \[Pi] && 0 <= b < 2 \[Pi] && 
       0 <= c < 2 Pi && 0 <= d < 2 Pi, {a, b, c, d}, Reals] // 
     FullSimplify];


Clear[B]; B = {{1,0,0,-1,0,0},{-1,-1,-1,0,-1,0},{0,1,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,1,-1},{0,0,1,1,0,0}};
GraphPlot[UndirectedGraph[IncidenceGraph[B]], 
 VertexLabels -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Small, 
 PlotLabel -> "graph 22224"]
Func5[B]
```

The result is as follows

[image]

How to convert it to the below form?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`SolveValues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SolveValues.html) with `Method -> Reduce`

```
Func5[B_] := 
  Module[{a, b, c, sa, ca, sb, cb, sc, cc, sd, cd, vec, trigs, polys, 
    allfuns, gb, sol, oldeqns, neweqns}, vec = {a, b, c, d, 0};
   trigs = -B . Sin[Transpose[B] . vec];
   polys = 
    TrigExpand /@ trigs /. {Sin[a] -> sa, Sin[b] -> sb, Sin[c] -> sc, 
      Sin[d] -> sd, Cos[a] -> ca, Cos[b] -> cb, Cos[c] -> cc, 
      Cos[d] -> cd};
   allfuns = 
    Join[
     polys, {sa^2 + ca^2 - 1, sb^2 + cb^2 - 1, sc^2 + cc^2 - 1, 
      sd^2 + cd^2 - 1}];
   gb = GroebnerBasis[allfuns, {sa, sb, sc, sd}, {ca, cb, cc, cd}];
   sol = 
    Reduce[gb == 0] /. {sa -> Sin[a], sb -> Sin[b], sc -> Sin[c], 
      sd -> Sin[d], ca -> Cos[a], cb -> Cos[b], cc -> Cos[c], 
      cd -> Cos[d]};
   oldeqns = And @@ Thread[trigs == 0];
   neweqns = FullSimplify[oldeqns && sol];
   all1 = Union[allfuns, gb];
   SolveValues[
    neweqns && 0 <= a < 2 π && 0 <= b < 2 π && 0 <= c < 2 Pi &&
      0 <= d < 2 Pi, {a, b, c, d}, Reals, Method -> Reduce]];
```

Graphing,

```
Clear[B]; B = {{1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0}, {-1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 
   0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}};
GraphPlot[UndirectedGraph[IncidenceGraph[B]], 
 VertexLabels -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Small, 
 PlotLabel -> "graph 22224"]
```

[image]

```
Func5[B]

(* {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, π}, {0, 0, (2 π)/3, (4 π)/3}, {0,
   0, π, 0}, {0, 0, π, π}, {0, 0, (4 π)/3, (2 π)/
  3}, {0, π, 0, 0}, {0, π, 0, π}, {0, π, π/3, (
  5 π)/3}, {0, π, π, 
  0}, {0, π, π, π}, {0, π, (5 π)/3, π/3}, {(
  2 π)/3, (4 π)/3, 0, (2 π)/3}, {(2 π)/3, (4 π)/
  3, π/3, π/3}, {(2 π)/3, (4 π)/3, π/3, (4 π)/
  3}, {(2 π)/3, (4 π)/3, (2 π)/3, 0}, {(2 π)/3, (
  4 π)/3, (4 π)/3, π/3}, {(2 π)/3, (4 π)/3, (
  4 π)/3, (4 π)/3}, {π, 0, 0, 0}, {π, 0, 
  0, π}, {π, 0, (2 π)/3, (4 π)/3}, {π, 0, π, 
  0}, {π, 0, π, π}, {π, 0, (4 π)/3, (2 π)/
  3}, {π, π, 0, 0}, {π, π, 
  0, π}, {π, π, π/3, (5 π)/
  3}, {π, π, π, 
  0}, {π, π, π, π}, {π, π, (5 π)/3, π/
  3}, {(4 π)/3, (2 π)/3, 0, (4 π)/3}, {(4 π)/3, (
  2 π)/3, (2 π)/3, (2 π)/3}, {(4 π)/3, (2 π)/3, (
  2 π)/3, (5 π)/3}, {(4 π)/3, (2 π)/3, (4 π)/3, 
  0}, {(4 π)/3, (2 π)/3, (5 π)/3, (2 π)/3}, {(
  4 π)/3, (2 π)/3, (5 π)/3, (5 π)/3}} *)
```

Comment: Sweet! I keep forgetting about the *Values functions.

Comment: What version are using? `Version 12` does not have the option `SolveValues`. Perhaps you could update your answer to include that small bit of information as well

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0 - `SolveValues` was introduced in v12.3. In earlier version just use `{a, b, c, d} /. Solve[ ... ]`

Comment: Yeah, I know :) 
I just mentioned it for the author of the OP or others. Thanks for the clarification in case and wonderful stuff as always!

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to write a function that recursively walks the tree, doing the appropriate splitting for And and Or along the way, and then Sows the solutions (wrap the whole thing in Reap).

I was too lazy for that, so here's a brute force solution.

```
solution = Func5[B];

(* the next bit finds all the lowest level variable assignments and forces them into a replacement rule for the variable involved *)
assignments = GatherBy[Flatten[Solve /@ Cases[solution, _Equal, Infinity]], First]

(* next we just make all combinations of these variable assignments *)
candidates = Tuples[assignments];
candidates // Short

(*
{{b$50899->0,d->0,c$50899->0,a$50899->0},{b$50899->0,d->0,c$50899->0,a$50899->\[Pi]},<<4093>>,{b$50899->(2 \[Pi])/3,d->0,c$50899->(4 \[Pi])/3,a$50899->(4 \[Pi])/3}}
*)

(* any of these assignment groups that cause the solution to equal 
True is a solution! so, let's make this explicit with a test function *)
isSolution[solution_][candidate_] := solution /. candidate

(* let's filter our list of assigment groups with this function *)
simpleSolutions = Select[candidates, isSolution[solution]];
simpleSolutions // Short

(*
{{b$50899->0,d->0,c$50899->0,a$50899->0},{b$50899->0,d->0,c$50899->0,a$50899->\[Pi]},<<291>>,{b$50899->(2 \[Pi])/3,d->0,c$50899->(4 \[Pi])/3,a$50899->(4 \[Pi])/3}}
*)
```

This leaves lists of Rules instead of lists of atomic numbers, but I didn't want to assume an ordering. You can come up with the ordering you want, sort by that, and pull out the raw numbers.